# Maas Import boot image error: connection refused

Tags: maas

I installed Ubuntu 14.04
when i run `sudo maas-import-pxe-files` i'll get this error:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool( host='maas.ubuntu.com, port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /images/ephemeral-v2/releases/streams/v1/index.json ( Caused by <class'Socket:error'> [Errno 111] connection refused)
```

or when I click 'Import Boot Images' nothing downloaded!

I this cas you must config the network on MAAS setting page.
I think it is better to return back a better error in log ,something like check you proxy!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed error by:

```
sudo http_proxy=http://?.?.?.?:8080/ maas-import-pxe-files
```